# Objective C: When to use methods in App Delegate and when to use methods in View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I am a little confused on the following methods in both my View Controller and App delegate classes

Method in App delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Method in ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

Under what situation do I need to add code in the app delegate or ViewController methods? I believe that for switching of views, we need to include it in the app delegate method, are there any rules of thumb that we need to abide by?

Thanks!

Zhen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:* should be used for setup that must occur when the application is launched, e.g.

- Core Data stack
- Restoring application state
- Creating application navigation controllers or tab bars

*viewDidLoad* should be used for any configuration that only needs to be done for that specific view controller. In some cases the view may not get loaded, so there's no point doing that configuration in the app delegate.

e.g

- Opening an HTTP connection when the view loads
- Asking for location data for a view

Answer (score 3):

As it is called at launch,`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` typically contains logic to initialise your application (e.g. setting up core data objects, registering for push notifications, etc.). The purpose of `viewDidLoad` on the other hand is to initialise your view controller before it is shown.